# How to create a draggable google map

Tags: ionic-framework

I just want that marker should be in centre and map should be draggable

```
getCurrentLocation() {

    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
      let geo = new google.maps.Geocoder;
      this.location.lat = position.coords.latitude;
      this.location.lng = position.coords.longitude;
      var latlng = { lat: this.location.lat, lng: this.location.lng };

      geo.geocode({ 'location': latlng }, (results) => {
        if (results.length) {
          let address = results[0];

          this.position = {
            lat: address.geometry.location.lat,
            lng: address.geometry.location.lng,
            name: address.address_components[1].long_name,
            dsc: address.formatted_address,
          };
          console.log(this.position, 'address current')
        }
      });
    });

    this.mapOptions = {
      center: this.location,
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      draggable: true, //map is draggable but marker doesnt stay in centre
    };

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, this.mapOptions);
      this.markerOptions.position = this.location;
      this.markerOptions.map = this.map;
      this.markerOptions.title = 'My Location';
      this.marker = new google.maps.Marker(this.markerOptions);
    }, 3000);
  }
```

when user open the map, when he is able to move the map, map should be draggable and marker should be in centre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope!! this helps any one...

```
addMarker() {

    setTimeout(() => {
         this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, this.mapOptions);
         this.markerOptions.position = this.map.getCenter();
         this.markerOptions.map = this.map;
         this.markerOptions.draggable = false;
         this.markerOptions.title = 'My Location';
         this.marker = new google.maps.Marker(this.markerOptions);
         this.marker.bindTo('position', this.map, 'center');   //bind marker to be in center


      google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, 'dragend', () => {
        this.map.setCenter(this.marker.getPosition()); // Set map center to marker position
      });

     google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'dragend', () => {
       this.marker.setPosition(this.map.getCenter()); // set marker position to map center          
    });
  }, 100);
}
```

or else another way also:

Visit this link: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/jcHqt/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to solve ur issue [map-how-to-keep-marker-in-center](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/in-ionic-naitve-google-map-how-to-keep-marker-in-center-when-i-drag-map-or-on-camera-move-start-like-uber-do-or-careem/143573/2)

```
<div id="map_canvas">
   <img src="assets/marker.png" id="centerMarkerImg">
</div>
```

> css

```
#map_canvas {
  position: relative;
}
#centerMarkerImage {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom:0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 32px; // image width
  height: 24px; // image height
  z-index: 1;
}
```

> .ts

```
export class HomePage {
  dummyMarker: any;
  mapDragMode: boolean = false;
  centerPos: any;

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.dummyMarker = document.getElementById("centerMarkerImg");
    this.dummyMarker.style.display = 'none';
  }

  loadMap() {
     this.map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.CAMERA_CHANGE).subscribe((params: any[]) => {
       if (!this.mapDragMode) {
         return;
       }
       const cameraPosition: any = params[0];
       this.centerPos = cameraPosition.target;
     });
   }
  start() : {
    this.mapDragMode = true;
    this.dummyMarker.style.display = 'block';
  }

  end() : {
    this.mapDragMode = false;
    this.dummyMarker.style.display = 'none';
  }

}
```

Comment: self=this if its hard try second example it have example code

Comment: wich service page

Comment: do you checked it